# Changing the visibility of views one at a time with a button

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-button, android-looper

I have three views which visibility is currently set to `view.setVisibility(view.GONE)` and I have a button which I want to change the visibilities to visible one at a time as the user keeps clicking the button. I think I have to use a for loop centred on the button click but I don't know how. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = 0;

onClick(View v){
   switch(++i){
       case 1:
         view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         break;
       case 2:
         view2 setVisibility(View.GONE);
         break;
       case 3:
         view3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         i = 0;
         break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an array with your views and a variable to know which view is now visible:

```
View[] views; // put your 3 views inside (0 will be first shown)
int position = 3;
```

Inside button listener simply change the views visibility:

> NOTE the use of static `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE`

```
// hide the view
views[position].setVisibility(View.GONE);
// change the position
position = position == 3 ? 0 : position++; 
// show new view
views[position].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

maintain a flag
`int clickEventFlag = 0`

on your button click use

```
clickEventFlag++;

switch(clickEventFlag % 3){
    case 0:
         //set visible first view
         break;
    case 1:
         //set visible second view
         break;
    case 2:
         //set visible third view
         break;

 }
```

Comment: yes but you accept that as a solution, so you can modify that instead of downvoting

Comment: nope, I CAN'T modify your code, but I don't downvoted because is ugly I did it because you didn't hide the views in any moment, so after 2 clicks you will see the three views...

Comment: also, downvote a valid answer because of your rage is really according to SO rules ;)

Comment: Sir,
Due to "switch(clickEventFlag % 3)" you have to use:
if(view.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE){
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

Comment: @Md.SajedulKarim Actually I was not concern about view visible or gone. I was just trying to show him how he can achieve what he wants. Means in that switch case block he can use his logic to achieve what he wants.

Comment: @BojanKseneman your answer was perfect. I am using it although, somehow it has been deleted. Kunu your answer works good but it is based on remainder. So I decided to continue using Bojan's answer. Thanks everybody. So much.